# Widget configure activity does not create the widget

Tags: android-widget, actionbarsherlock, single-instance, launchmode

I'm using a `SherlockFragmentActivity` as a widget configure activity:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:configure="com.tahanot.activities.MyActivity"
    ...
```

Why I create a new widget, the activity opens, but when it ends, no widget is created although I make it return an OK result:

```
Intent resultValue = new Intent();
resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
finish();
```

It used to work when I had a different (non-Sherlock) configure activity, and I can't figure out why it doesn't work with this one. Maybe a `SherlockFragmentActivity` cannot act as a configure activity? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that Sherlock was innocent, my problem was something else altogether.

Apparently, **a widget configuration activity cannot have `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`**. A `singleInstance` activity just never creates a widget! So I changed it to `singleTop` and now it works.

This is also referred to in this question: [Android AppWidget Configuration - Start in new task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235062/android-appwidget-configuration-start-in-new-task)